# What's the best way to make a Qt executable program run as a service in Ubuntu

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, upstart, qt, init.d

I've written my Qt code for an embedded system which is running on Ubuntu.

I want to run my program as a service in Ubuntu so I can stop or start it using `monit`. I've seen some people creating a new file in `/etc/init.d` and adding their executable file path in there.

But I want to know what's the best way to run my program as a service ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, Most `init` services were replaced with [`upstart`](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/) jobs.

Here is place where to start http://upstart.ubuntu.com/getting-started.html .

Answer (score 0):

Programs started from `/etc/init.d` (or, rather, from `/etc/init` in case of upstart) are called [daemons](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daemon_%28computing%29) and they usually run as background processes with all their output redirected to a logfile. Daemons are often started on system boot and don't depend on a GUI session running, or on user logging into their account etc.

Normal, "user space" graphical programs are quite different - Qt applications are usually started from within an X session, and technically are "children" of the X process, so when X exits the application is terminated. Conceptually, there may be multiple X sessions running on a machine at the same time, with a separate copy of your application running in each one, so the idea of adding your app's startup script to `/etc/init.d` wouldn't cut it even in principle.

It is possible to do something similar to what you want by configuring X that it automatically starts your application on startup. Going further, you may use a minimalistic window manager which would only run your application maximized fullscreen. This is called "kiosk mode" - you can find a few tutorials on the web. For example, here's a quersion on Unix&Linux: [Debian based system, only one gui program, nothing else](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/30207/debian-based-system-only-one-gui-program-nothing-else/30209#30209)

Comment: Okay, I'll check it and see if it works for me or not, then I'll hit the answer . Thanks sergey

Comment: @Sergey Why do you think OPs program has a GUI or that it needs to be started in X context?